# Circle masking for image cropping in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to give a circular mask to image view and I have to crop the image portion in circular area, which is working fine. But I am facing some problem with the mask, which is annotated in the attached image.[image: Masking an image for cropping feature]

Following are pieces of code which I have used to mask.

**Adding mask to image view layer**

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
self.maskLayer = maskLayer;
```

**create shape layer for circle we'll draw on top of image (the boundary of the circle)**

```
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circleLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
circleLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
circleLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
self.circleLayer = circleLayer;
```

**create circle path**

```
[self updateCirclePathAtLocation:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0) radius:self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.30];

- (void)updateCirclePathAtLocation:(CGPoint)location radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    self.circleCenter = location;
    self.circleRadius = radius;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path addArcWithCenter:self.circleCenter
                    radius:self.circleRadius
                startAngle:0.0
                  endAngle:M_PI * 2.0
                 clockwise:YES];

    /*
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1] setFill];
    [path fill];
    */

    self.maskLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    self.circleLayer.path = [path CGPath];
}
```

Can anyone give a suggestion to make the white area around the circular mask to be partially visible or apply transparent CGColor using alpha?

Comment: Could you create a rectangular CAShapeLayer with the centre removed instead of masking? Then apply a background colour to the layer?

Comment: Actually, my requirement is to give circular shape rather than rectangle.

Comment: Ah sorry, i'll be more specific with my description. A rectangular CAShapeLayer that matches the area labeled as "Loaded Image Area" in your diagram. So this will cover the entire image. Then use a `UIBezierPath` to remove a circle in the centre of the layer

Comment: DO you want to do something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643266/how-to-make-a-transparent-cut-on-uivisualeffectview. I have the rectangular cut, and you can make it any shape.

Comment: Yes Teja, I want to do something like that. Do you have the working code for the same?

Comment: @Ollie The above code is that I have been used. Can you suggest some minor tweaks in above code to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I did is:

I placed a `UIView` on top of `UIImageView`, and I made a transparent hole in the top `UIView`, so that bottom image can be seen through that view.

Here is the `drawRect` of the UIView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Clear any existing drawing on this view
    // Remove this if the hole never changes on redraws of the UIView
    CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);

    // Create a path around the entire view
    UIBezierPath *clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];

    // Your transparent window. This is for reference, but set this either as a property of the class or some other way
    CGRect transparentFrame; //this is the frame of the hole
    // Add the transparent window
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:transparentFrame cornerRadius:5.0f];
    [clipPath appendPath:path];

    // NOTE: If you want to add more holes, simply create another UIBezierPath and call [clipPath appendPath:anotherPath];

    // This sets the algorithm used to determine what gets filled and what doesn't
    clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
    // Add the clipping to the graphics context
    [clipPath addClip];

    // set your color
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 

    // (optional) set transparency alpha
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.7f);
    // tell the color to be a fill color
    [tintColor setFill];
    // fill the path
    [clipPath fill];
}
```

Here I have used the bezierWithROundedRect and you can use bezierWIthArc to get the circular bezier.

You will get something like this:

[image]

You can adjust the alpha of topView to get the desired transparency.
 By this way, you can also move the hole by touch and the view gets redrawn based on your touch location.