# How to clip one section of a view to clip out with another view and make it look see through.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am having following scenario:

1. There is a parent view controller which displays **view A**. Takes whole screen to display its content.
2. To **view A**, I'm adding `addSubView: ViewB`. Now **View B** here is covering some portion of the screen partially over **A**, and user can see that part of **view A** which is not covered by **view B**.
3. Now I'm trying to create a **view C** and want to add it to **view B**  `addSubView: ViewC`, such that it overlays over **view B**, only to clip out a portion of **View B**, so that the user can see through that underlying portion of **View A**.

Question:

How can I go through writing properties of **view C controller** such that I can accomplish this clipping effect.

Comment: Please share some code. Could you please also clarify clipping effect?

Comment: @casillas There are actually nothing I can share at this point. All I'm working with is regular UIViews and sub UIViews. My question is about an completely new feature. To be precise, I'm not stuck at any bug, which would require sharing and correcting.

Comment: Lots of examples out there to do what you want. Start with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711248/cut-transparent-hole-in-uiview

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165751/circle-masking-for-image-cropping-in-ios/39206146#39206146

Comment: Maybe try to use custom drawing for viewB using UIBezierPath

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I spend last couple of days implementing this solution. It is more relevant towards what I'm trying to achieve. Now the problem is that if my View has child UI elements like UIWebView, then the clipping seems not working.

Comment: you can cover the webview with a uiview and apply the clipping! @ikis

Comment: @ZuzanaPaulis yes. I'm trying that now and seems like it's working but there are more to it which seems not working. Check my previous comments. ^

Comment: I use paint code app to figure out drawing. It's a great tool

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I'm towards this direction now.

Comment: @ZuzanaPaulis thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try. 